# How to enable the equalizer on mobile

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

```
   <div class="row mobile-horizontial-scroll" data-equalizer data-options="equalize_on_stack: true">
        <?php

        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('columns') ):

            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('columns') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="column small-10 medium-4 margin-bottom-xsmall text-center">
                    <div class="panel-white medium-text-center column-padding" data-equalizer-watch>
                        <img src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="" />
                        <h5 class="heading-orange heading-padding-small"><?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?></h5>
                        <?php echo the_sub_field('description'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile;

        else : ?>
        <div class="column small-12">
            <p>
                No Data Found!, please enter data in the columns field in the admin
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to make the equalizer from foundation. In the documentation is says about using this attr data-options="equalize_on_stack: true" which I thought would enable equalizer on mobile but has seemed to fail.

Has anyone be able to make equalizer work on mobile?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Already tried the data attribute `data-equalize-on`?

From the docs;

> data-equalize-on - medium - Representing the minimum breakpoint size the plugin should equalize heights on.